# Apache rewrite rules behind a nginx proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I am running nginx (:80) in front of an Apache webserver (:8080)

Nginx config (snippet):

```
location / {
    proxy_pass        http://www.domain.tld:8080;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
```

If I set localhost instead of www.domain.tld, my browser gets redirected to http://localhost:8080.

Apache rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !v2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ v1/$1 [L]
```

So far, so good.

However, every link (which uses relative paths) appears as http://www.domain.tld:8080/page instead of staying on port 80.

Is there any way to solve this through the rewrite rules? I don't want to use absolute paths.

Thanks

Comment: Solved by adding this to the nginx config: (1) proxy_set_header Host $host;
 (2) proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

Comment: You can also write an answer yourself and accept it, that way this question won't look like it is "unanswered".

Comment: In fact @Tuinslak you *should* answer your own question, remove the "** Solved **" from the question itself, and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding this to the nginx config:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host; 
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```